# Глагольно-именные сочетания со словом "спор"

Tags: словосочетания

Может ли спор не только "завязаться", но и "развязаться" в значении "начаться"?

Comment: Вы бы заглянули в http://www.ruscorpora.ru/old/search-main.html или https://keywordtool.io/ru

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Не может: в этой паре глаголов приставки задают "направленность" обозначаемого действия.

В словаре Ушакова приводится (ныне редко употребляемый) вариант **развязать (спор)**, но в *противоположном* значении (по аналогии с *развязыванием* узла, с распутыванием чего-то запутанного): **разрешить** (чей-либо) **спор** - что означает *внести ясность в чужой спор **со стороны***; обычно это приводит к его прекращению. Трудно представить себе употреление в подобной ситуации глагола "развязаться" (спор развязался кем-то?), в то время как "разрешиться" спор может вполне (напр. с появлением новой информации, с которой согласны спорящие).